# Updating rotue MKRoute or GMSPath in real time

Tags: ios, google-maps, mapkit

Uber uses Google Maps GMSPath which can be returned from their directions API, but Apple maps offers `MKRoute` via its `MKDirections` API (there are some offerings from mapbox as well).

Both `GMSPath` and `MKRoute` are read only. I can successfully return a response given a start and end point.

But how do I update this `GMSPath` or `MKRoute` path in realtime while driving along this route? This includes the UBer like animation of trimming the blue line `GMSPath` as the driver drivers along it, as well as reload the directions if a wrong turn is made.

I was thinking of just longpolling the directions and redrawing them every change in location that is X distance apart. Is there a better way to animate this?

See similar question

[MKRoute update MKPolyline Overlay when current Location changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779235/mkroute-update-mkpolyline-overlay-when-current-location-changes)

Comment: hmm...Seems thats the only way you can do to redraw a polyline between origin and destination. There is no real time API can let you listen to route changes and redraw at this time, I think.

Comment: Well route changes is an extra complexity, but at the very least I know that the `Breadcrumb` sample app deals with editing a polyline by adding (not deleting) `MKMapPoints` into a `CGPath` for rendering on a map. `https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Breadcrumb/Listings/Breadcrumb_CrumbPathRenderer_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010048-Breadcrumb_CrumbPathRenderer_h-DontLinkElementID_7`

Comment: hey had you got any success in this? I am currently updating route by removing the old one and applying new route